# hadoop 2.6: local-dirs are bad: unhealthy node

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to setup hadoop 2.6 on pseudo distributed mode. I followed all the steps. But for some reason, my nodes are unhealthy.

```
1/1 local-dirs are bad: /home/hduser/hadoop_tmp/nm-local-dir; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /home/hduser/hadoop/logs/userlogs
```

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131449/hadoop-unhealthy-node-local-dirs-are-bad-tmp-hadoop-hduser-nm-local-dir would help.