# Why does Hadoop report "Unhealthy Node local-dirs and log-dirs are bad"?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to setup a single-node Hadoop 2.6.0 cluster on my PC.

On visiting http://localhost:8088/cluster, I find that my node is listed as an "unhealthy node".

In the health report, it provides the error:

```
1/1 local-dirs are bad: /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir; 
1/1 log-dirs are bad: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs
```

What's wrong?

Comment: This won't fix the root cause, but will get you going for the time being:
Add property 'yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.min-healthy-disks' in yarn-site.xml and set value to 0.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The most common cause of `local-dirs are bad` is due to available disk space on the node exceeding yarn's `max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage` default value of `90.0%`.

Either clean up the disk that the unhealthy node is running on, or increase the threshold in `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
  <value>98.5</value>
</property>
```

Avoid disabling disk check, because your jobs may failed when the disk eventually run out of space, or if there are permission issues. Refer to the [yarn-site.xml  Disk Checker section](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManager.html#Disk_Checker) for more details.

### FSCK

If you suspect there is filesystem error on the directory, you can check by running

```
hdfs fsck /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir
```

Comment: is it ok to store fs on /tmp?

Comment: No, not too much free space @Dims. The way I read that was "exceeded max-utilization" so that means `too much` disk space is being used. (The amount being used is above the allowed amount--threshold.)

Comment: For me it was caused by someone writing a really bad query. I'm not sure why that was filling up all the local disks but killing a few jobs got everything working again. All the usage was in the /tmp directory. Usage went from 90%+ down to 20% straight away. I didn't delete any files manually.

Answer (score 9):

Please try to add the config in yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.enable</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>
```

It can work on my site.

And rm the /usr/local/hadoop/logs. 
ex:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/hadoop/logs
mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/logs
```

Comment: Well, I've tried a multitude of suggestions, including yours. it seems to be working now. I'm not sure which suggestion correctly resolved the issue though.

Comment: @Ra41P The last one only removes the log files, which should not affect the process, so it has to be adding the configuration

Comment: even if hadoop finds out that your system is running out of disk space while trying to write to the logs folder the problem can be everywhere! `du -h` might help you to reveal the folders in question. In our case it wasn't the logs that ran full but some journaling files in some totally different folders.

Comment: You should not disable the disk health check. If you let this problem go, you're disks are just going to fill up 100% before much longer and you're going to crash anyways.

Answer (score 3):

It can be also caused by the wrong log directory location configured by  `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` in `yarn-site.xml`. Either by the fact directory does not exist or has wrong permissions set.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue at first.

Then I also found another problem. When I used jps command some processes like NameNode, DataNode etc. were missing.

```
$jps
13696 Jps
12949 ResourceManager
13116 NodeManager
```

Then I fixed it from the following 
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910805/)
 and the unhealthy node issue was automatically fixed.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS with Hadoop installed using `brew` I had to change `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml` to include the following:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.min-healthy-disks</name>
  <value>0</value>
</property>
```

The setting has basically turned the disk health check off completely

I found the file using `brew list hadoop`.

```
$ brew list hadoop | grep yarn-site.xml
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.8.1/libexec/share/hadoop/tools/sls/sample-conf/yarn-site.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, sqoop upload just hanged when hdfs reached 90%. After I changed a treshold for max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage and alarm treshold definitions upload is working again. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this when the disk is 90% (using >df) and I take off unnecessary files so it became 85% (the default setting for yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage is using 90% of available disk if you do not specify in yarn-site.xml) and the problem is solved.

The effect is similar to increase utilization to over 90% (so to squeeze extra available space in my case was 90% full) just to squeeze extra space. However it is good practice not to reach over 90% anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, list my causes, FYR:

1. dirs not exists, `mkdir` first,
2. memory-mb set is too larger than available

```xml
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>/tmp/yarn/nm</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
        <value>/tmp/yarn/container-logs</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>364000</value>
    </property>
```