# MapReduce not starting on Single Node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hipi

I need help, I have installed hadoop-2.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 with HIPI configuration and all services are up and running.However while running jar file and using the following command doesnt execute a map-reduce job: hadoop jar faceCount.jar /project/input.hib and project/output

The job is planned but nothing is happening...

[image]

This is http://macvaio-vpceh28fn:8088/cluster

[image]

Comment: check you have enough resource (core and memory) by logging to yarn web console

Comment: How do I check it? I am newbie, can you explain in detail? @NirmalRam

Comment: go to yarn web console http://macvalo-VPCEH28FN:8088/cluster and check Memory Total  and VCores Total

Comment: I have added console screeenshot.Take a look, and please tell me what to change and how to do it. @NirmalRam

Comment: it seems Yarn nodemanager is not running. See Active Nodes is 0

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131449/hadoop-unhealthy-node-local-dirs-are-bad-tmp-hadoop-hduser-nm-local-dir