# MapReduce Jobs failing, after accepted by YARN

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Even a simple WordCount mapreduce also fails with same error.

Hadoop 2.6.0

Below are the Yarn logs.

It seems some sort of timeout happens during resource negotiation.
But i am unable to verify the same, exactly what causes timeout.

> 2016-11-11 15:38:09,313 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher:
>   Error launching appattempt_1478856936677_0004_000002. Got exception:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting
>   for channel to be ready for read. ch :
>   java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.0.37.145:49054
>   remote=platform-demo/10.0.37.145:60487]; Host Details : local host is:
>   "platform-demo/10.0.37.145"; destination host is:
>   "platform-demo":60487;
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1472)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.startContainers(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.startContainers(ContainerManagementProtocolPBClientImpl.java:96)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.launch(AMLauncher.java:119)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.amlauncher.AMLauncher.run(AMLauncher.java:254)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis
>   timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch :
>   java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.0.37.145:49054
>   remote=platform-demo/10.0.37.145:60487]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:680)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:643)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:730)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
>           ... 9 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch :
>   java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.0.37.145:49054
>   remote=platform-demo/10.0.37.145:60487]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:164)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
>           at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
>           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
>           at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
>           at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:367)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:553)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:368)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:722)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:718)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:717)
>           ... 12 more
>
> 2016-11-11 15:38:09,319 INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl:
>   Updating application attempt appattempt_1478856936677_0004_000002 with
>   final state: FAILED, and exit status: -1000 2016-11-11 15:38:09,319
>   INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl:
>   appattempt_1478856936677_0004_000002 State change from ALLOCATED to
>   FINAL_SAVING

I tried to change below properties

> yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
>   2200   Amount of physical memory, in MB,
>   that can be allocated for containers.
>
> yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb
>   500
>
> dfs.datanode.socket.write.timeout
>   3000000
>
> dfs.socket.timeout   3000000

Comment: can you share the mapreduce job command and yarn web UI?

Comment: Show us the output of `netstat -tapun` and the content of your `/etc/hosts`, please.

Comment: host_file -- http://pastebin.com/MQbfQGUy

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa please find netsat output http://pastebin.com/esKK6CdP

Comment: Hi @AlfonsoNishikawa thanks i get many connections to 60487, I fixed it.   But now there is different issue after job scheduled, job hangs . Yarn logs on following location :----http://pastebin.com/4c17Kv73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1.MapReduce Jobs failing, after accepted by YARN

Reason, multiple connections around 130 stuck on port 60487.

Q2.MapReduce Jobs failing, after accepted by YARN

Issue is due to hadoop tmp /app/hadoop/tmp.  Empty this directory and re-tried MAPR job, job was executed successfully.

Q3.Unhealthy Node local-dirs are bad: /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir

Edit yarn-site.xml with folowing property.

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage</name>
        <value>98.5</value>
</property>
```

Refer [Why does Hadoop report "Unhealthy Node local-dirs and log-dirs are bad"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131449/hadoop-unhealthy-node-local-dirs-are-bad-tmp-hadoop-hduser-nm-local-dir)