# OOZIE stuck in RUNING status

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I use OOZIE to run a workflow. But a simple official example `shell-wf` (echo `hello oozie`) stuck in RUNNING state and never end. The workflow can be submitted but stuck at RUNNING state. There is not any error in job log in OOZIE UI.

When submitting a shell with `spark-submit` inside, the job will be never submitted and can not be seen in Spark UI. I suspect the shell didn't run at all.

What's the possible problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Quick Checklist

For those who have the same problem, there is a checklist to check your system. Hope it helps!

1. Check `jobTracker` in your Oozie configuration. **Note**: If a job has been successfully run, it probably not the problem of `jobTracker`. Related discussion can be found [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/186254/oozie-job-stuck-in-running-state-always.html)
2. Check your disk usage. If ## Heading ##disk usage is greater than 90%, remove some files to make sure disk usage is less than 90%. (That's my case!)
3. Check `Console URL` of the stuck action. It can be found in `Job - Job Info tab - Actions - Action - Action Info tab`. Job state here may help you to find the problem.
4. Check Oozie log. It's typically in `/usr/local/oozie/logs`. Check `oozie.log*` to find if there are exceptions.

### Details

#### Disk usage

If your action state is

> YarnApplicationState: ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.

That may be the disk problem. Relative discussion can be found in [MapReduce job hangs, waiting for AM container to be allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467308/mapreduce-job-hangs-waiting-for-am-container-to-be-allocated). Solutions can be found in [Why does Hadoop report "Unhealthy Node local-dirs and log-dirs are bad"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131449/why-does-hadoop-report-unhealthy-node-local-dirs-and-log-dirs-are-bad).